# C++ Program exits loop before condition is false

Tags: c++, loops

This method takes a vector (inputVector, member variable) and splits it into char*[]'s.  Whenever you come across a ";" in the vector, print out the last set of char*s stored in args.  Even though the vector size is 14, the loop exits on the 5th loop.

**Vector data (newline separates items):**
/bin/echo
killroy
was
here;
;
xyzzy
;
nonexistent-program
;
/bin/true
;
/bin/false
;

```
void TrivialShell::splitArguments() {

    char* args[MAX_ARGS];

    int inputVectorIdx = 0;
    int currentArgsIdx = 0;
    int startingArgsIdx = 0;

    while (inputVectorIdx < inputVector.size()) {

        if (inputVector[inputVectorIdx] == ";") {
            for (int k = startingArgsIdx; k <= currentArgsIdx; k++) {
                cout << args[k];
            }
            startingArgsIdx = currentArgsIdx + 1;
        }

        else {
            args[currentArgsIdx] = 
                const_cast<char*>(inputVector[inputVectorIdx].c_str());
        }

        inputVectorIdx++;
        currentArgsIdx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: But does it print the first four properly before exiting?

Comment: There's not enough code here to determine how it works

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Is there a reason you're converting your `std::string`s to `char*`s for this function?

Comment: what type is your inputVector?

Comment: It prints the first 4 correctly.

How is this not enough code?  The vector is populated correctly.

This is part of a homework assignment, I am converting the strings so that I can pass them into execv(args[0], args);

Comment: show how you declare & initialize vector

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/1227469) which solves your problem without C-style code in a much simpler way. Just use `std::string::c_str` at the point you actually need the `char*`, rather than in your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int k = startingArgsIdx; k < currentArgsIdx; k++) {
 //                             ^^
                cout << args[k];
}
```

You are trying to print one too much. You haven't said it but I am sure it doesn't just skip the loop but exits the program.

Comment: Of course!  Thanks so much, I knew it was something minor.  Fixed it

Comment: btw: in my case on my machine it contnues, it doesn't exit

Comment: @cf16 Maybe it might not exit. I think if it can print whatever garbage is in that location the it will just give you jibberish and continue. Maybe IDK.

Answer (score 1):

you have a bug. when you enter your loop

```
if (inputVector[inputVectorIdx] == ";") {
            for (int k = startingArgsIdx; k <= currentArgsIdx; k++) {
                cout << args[k];
            }
            startingArgsIdx = currentArgsIdx + 1;
        }
```

you have your index iterator currentArgsIdx bigger than your actual size of data in array `args`. So you are doing `cout<<args[3]` when there are some garbages there already. It is because you  ++ your index at the end of while loop:

```
inputVectorIdx++;
currentArgsIdx++;
```

arrange this in different way or change condition to be:

```
for (int k = startingArgsIdx; k < currentArgsIdx; k++) {
                               ^^^
                cout << args[k];
            }
```